# Replacing "." with "%2E" in Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails controller action that functions as shown:

```
def rand
    if !params.has_key?(:name)
      rand_mymodel = Mymodel.offset(rand(Mymodel.count)).first
      redirect_to "/crawl/" + rand_mymodel.name
    end
    @model = Mymodel.where("name = ?", params[:name])[0]
end
```

With the route:

```
get "crawl/:name" => "mymodel#rand"
get "crawl/" => "mymodel#rand"
```

How can I allow for a `.` to appear in the `:name` attribute but replace it with `%2E` in the route/URL (similar to how space is replaced with `%20`)

I want to allow for `.` to appear in `:name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the respective [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?

> By default the :id parameter doesn’t accept dots – this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within an :id add a constraint which overrides this – for example
>   :id => /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

The same is true for your `name`:

```
get "crawl/:name" => "mymodel#rand", name: /[^\/]+/
```